# Python 3.4 What is this list doing?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My Code is:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L2 = L
L2[2] = 'a'
L
```

this gives me:

```
[1, 2, 'a', 4]
```

could someone explain me please when I worked with L2 why L have changed?

Comment: Because you didn't make a copy of the list.

Comment: `L2` and `L` are both holding the same list; you just happen to be referencing it from two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L` and `L2` refer to same memory location.

Take the following example of how to copy a list variable to another variable.

```
>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> id(x)
141910924
>>> y = x
>>> id(y)
141910924
>>> z = list(x)
>>> id(z)
141676844
>>> x.append(10)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 10]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3]
```

use copy and deepcopy when we want to assign list values to other variables e.g.

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = [1,2,3, [4,5]]
>>> y = copy.copy(x)
>>> id(x)
141913324
>>> id(y)
139369964
>>> x.append(10)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
>>> x[3].append(20)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20]]
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
>>> x[3].append(50)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20, 50], 10]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 20], 10]
```